# React app consoling API_KEY from .env file but cannot fetch it

Tags: reactjs, variables, environment

When I am using it in my project it console out the correct API_KEY but when I run it on server it show invalid API_KEY error

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY );
console.log(stripePromise);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/canWc.png)

Comment: Did you try my answer? did it work?

Comment: looks like you're importing an .env variable into the react app which requires ```REACT_APP``` initial. This lets you have access to the environment variables within the react app. However, your front end and back end is completely different. Environment variables that you have access to in the frontend are not available in the backend. You need to create a new .env file in the backend and you can use it as you wish. Also, ```process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY``` is the public key which you don't need in the backend. You should have a private stripe key that you need to use in the backend.

Comment: I have to use it in my react project the problem is that when i am consoling my api key it show correct but when i am using it to fetch api then it show me invalid api key

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm package. save and load environment variables from a .env file into process.env.

Save the value of the REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY in the .env file and call the value of the REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY in your project like below:

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}`)
console.log(stripePromise);

console.log(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}`);
```